# NLTK stem words produces odd results

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

After running `nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer().stem_word(word)` I get many words with 'ing' cut off or 'y' swapped with 'i' . e.g. 'Quality' becomes 'Qualiti' and (even stranger) 'value' becomes 'valu'?

As the resulting words are not actual english words, I am not sure how am I meant to use them? My best guess is that I am meant to put the stem words into another function which will give me all the derived/child words from this stem (e.g. 'valu' would return `['valuing','valued', 'values', ...]`. Is there such a function?

Comment: Did you try lemmatizing these words? What were the results there?

Comment: The term used for what is being asked is **lexeme**.  So the better thing to do is to take the original pre-stemmed word and run it through such a function instead of the stemmed version to get all the lexemes for the word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stemming extracts the stem of the word by going through a series of transformation rules which strip off common suffixes and prefixes. Hence the result produced may not be an actual English word.
The general use of stemming is to normalize words so that they are considered the same. For example:

```
stem_word('value') == stem_word('valuing')
```

The stemmed words can then be indexed for searching. Same stemming is done with the incoming query so that query words match the stemmed words in the index when doing the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that particular function but in general a word stem means the root of the word and is not necessarily a legal english word.

Are you using the nltk book?  This chapter covers stemming:  http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch03.html